# index.js: Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin'

Tags: javascript, react-native

**> index.js: Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin'**

I fix this issue with comment plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
module.exports = function(api) {

```
return {
presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
// plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is not a problem it is just a solution on specific error

Answer (score 1):

`plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],` only required for reanimated v2 and above if you're using v1 then no need to use it and removing it will fix your problem. You can check the documentation for more details from [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/getting_started).